# How to count number of edges in a given graph?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, solution-verification

We are given a graph $G$ with 360 vertices and each vertex has a degree of either 3, or 4. Every vertex with degree 3 is adjacent to exactly 2 vertices of degree 3 and 1 vertex of degree 4. Every vertex with degree 4 is adjacent to exactly 1 vertex of degree 3 and 3 vertices of degree 4. Determine a number of edges in $G$.

I am curious about the correctness of my solution. Initially, we observe an equal number of vertices with degrees 3 and 4 - specifically, 180 vertices for each degree, as there is exactly 1 edge between each pair. Next, we analyze each type of vertex. Using the fact that the sum of vertex degree values is twice the number of edges, we determine that $\frac{180 \times 2}{2} = 180$ represents the number of edges between vertices of degree 3. Similarly, there are $\frac{180 \times 3}{2} = 270$ edges between vertices of degree 4. Consequently, the total count is $180 + 180 + 270 = 630$ edges. Can you identify any flaws in my reasoning? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Site policy for solution verification is that you have to "must identify precisely which step in the proof that is in doubt, and why so", as opposed to just saying "can you identify any flaws in my reasoning".